# Twython returning false value for tweet['retweeted']

Tags: python, twitter, twython

Hello I just got into Twython. I'm trying to prevent my script from trying to retweet a Tweet multiple times (as this will raise an Error)

So I figgured out if you have a tweet the `retweeted` key should return wether you already retweeted that tweet.

However I wrote this Script:

```
def develop(twitter, keyword, count):
    global TweetIds, tweetInsert, FollowCounts
    results = twitter.search(q=keyword,count=count,result_type = 'popular')
    tweets = results['statuses']
    for tweet in tweets:
        if not tweet['retweeted']:
            try:
                twitter.retweet(id=tweet['id'])
            except TwythonError as e:
                print(e)
```

And this was the output

```
Twitter API returned a 403 (Forbidden), You have already retweeted this tweet.
Twitter API returned a 403 (Forbidden), You have already retweeted this tweet.
Twitter API returned a 403 (Forbidden), You have already retweeted this tweet.
Twitter API returned a 403 (Forbidden), You have already retweeted this tweet.
Twitter API returned a 403 (Forbidden), You have already retweeted this tweet.
Twitter API returned a 403 (Forbidden), You have already retweeted this tweet.
Twitter API returned a 403 (Forbidden), You have already retweeted this tweet.
Twitter API returned a 403 (Forbidden), You have already retweeted this tweet.
```

So `tweet['retweeted']` did return `false` even tough it should've been `true`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key `'retweeted'` is used if you want to check if the tweet you are seeing is original or if it's retweeted. For example if I make a post and you check my post `'retweeted'` is going to be `False` but if I retweet from someone else the value of `'retweeted'` will be `True`.

What I've thought about preventing multiple retweets is to write the tweet id in a text file and check every time the file if you've already retweeted. I know this is not efficient at all but I am not sure about any other solution. To make it a bit faster you can create a new text everyday to minimize the number of ids you have run through to check. I hope I helped you